# How to handle a customer and an admin UI

Tags: jhipster

We are planning to start an application using JHipster. One of the requirements we have is, that there are quite different UIs for customers and administrators.

- Customer UI: This is the one with the nice, responsive design mainly displaying information to the customer.
- Admin UI: This is the one with lots of tables and details view. It doesn't have to be responsive.

What would be the best approach to handle this?

Our idea was to use the UI generated by JHipster as the admin UI. There you have the user management, the monitoring functionality and the generated tables and details for all the entities. We would move this UI to the context admin. Then we would start a completely separate SPA for the customer in the root context. This would require to change the build that both UIs are being build independently.

I would like to know your thoughts on how to solve this requirement and our idea.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what I have done.
When an admin user logs in they are presented with the default admin UI.
When a regular user logs in they are presented with a completely different UI.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @fergal_dd
That sounds like the login screen is the same for both and after the login, different user groups are being redirected to different UIs. Is that correct?
Do you have both UIs as part of one project and one jar?

Comment: That's exactly it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: I've also added a different UI for another role (so now I have admin, client and manager). So when a user of with role manager logs in they are presented with a different UI than client and admin.  I intend to continue using this patter for 2 other roles.. I probably won't customize the admin default UI.